# Im using backgroundworker to call a search for files function but its getting stuck for sometimes why?

Tags: c#

In the top of the `Form1` I have:

```
int searchTime;
        public TimeSpan ts_timeElapsed;
        DirectoryInfo dirinf = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
        List<FileSystemInfo> fsi = new List<FileSystemInfo>();
        List<string> texts = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            label6.Visible = false;
            searchTime = 0;
            label4.Visible = false;
        }
```

Then I have a button click which starts the `backgroundWorker`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            button1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Then the `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Search(".xml", dirinf, fsi);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);

        }
```

Then the `Search` function code:

```
public void Search(string strExtension,
                            DirectoryInfo di,
                            List<FileSystemInfo> pResult)
        {
            try
            {

                foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
                {
                    if (InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => label2.Text = fi.Name));
                    }
                    if (fi.Name == "MessageLog.xsl")
                    {
                        foreach (FileInfo fii in di.GetFiles())
                        {
                        if (fii.Extension == strExtension)
                            pResult.Add(fii);
                        }
                        if (InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => label4.Text = pResult.Count.ToString() + Environment.NewLine));
                        }

                    }
                }

                    foreach (DirectoryInfo diChild in di.GetDirectories())
                        Search(strExtension, diChild, pResult);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
```

The search starts at `c:\`. The program pauses for some seconds after searching about 5 files, then it continues for some seconds searching more files, then finally freezes. I can't event click anything, even if it's working with a backgroundworker.

Then after a few times, it searches fast and smooth, without pauses or freezes.

Why do the first few searches pause and freeze, but subsequent searches proceed smoothly?

Comment: Are you overwhelming the system with too many BeginInvokes? Can you do the updates at regular intervals (say 10 per sec) via the progress event?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a resource issue. Too many threads spinning up, or a very large file or directory getting loaded up.

Comment: Do you have only one `BackgroundWorker` running at a time? I see some timer in your `button1_click` event handler....I've tested your code at my PC and it works without any delays (though I replaced MessageLog.xsl with just *.exe files), but I had only onr BW running?